# Attachment in mail client for ipad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer

I am trying to build a mail client app. for ipad that allows you to attach files.
Currently this feature is not supported by native mail.app

I checked some app like good reader and pdf reader lite that allows you to send one file in your email.
They embed the pdf file in the body of email.

So my question is,  how are they doing it.

Are they using any kind of APIs(which one) or are are they embeding the pdf in HTML?

Thanx.

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html

The method you are looking for is `addAttachmentData:`